# How does socket.io volatile flag work internally?

Tags: socket.io

i am emiting data with the volatile flag - 2 clients are connected. 1 client receives the message, the other does not. can someone explain me when socket.io drops a message due to volatile flag?

Answer (score 0):

With socket.io there are many different ways to emit these messages. Here is a cheat-sheet that might already help you: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).